# To get logs information in between particular time-stamp using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract infromation from logs using a shell script for a particular time range . A line in logs looks like this:

```
[16:34:34:911][13-10-2015]:No free accounts available
```

I need to extract data in specific intervals. for example in between 16:00 to 17:00 .I am new to shell script.I have tried with grep command . Can anyone suggest me how to do this ?

Comment: try something like `grep '^\[16:[[:digit:]]\{2,2\}:[[:digit:]]\{2,2\}:[[:digit:]]\{3,3\}\]' input.txt`. note that this wont get entries at 17 on the dot

Comment: @amdixon want to do it periodically. So everytime I just need to enter desired time stamp(in between particular seconds or mins or hours too) to extract the logs between those time stamp from logs.

Comment: and `grep '^\[16:3' input.txt` or when you want exact date as well `grep '^\[16' input.txt | grep '\[13-10'` 
This will return you the lines that start with 16 hours, and from that output it will grep the date 13-10 if you need it like that. 
Or if you want to use AND with grep , in case lets say you want 16h and 17 together : `grep '^\[16\|^\[17' input.txt`